# Interchanging limit and expectation in Ito Isometry proof

Tags: real-analysis, probability

Let $\phi_n$ be a sequence of elementary functions and $f$ a function satisfying:

1. $f(t,\omega)$ is measurable wrt $\mathcal{B}\times \mathcal{F}$
2. $f(t,\omega)$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$-adapted
3. $E\left[\int_S^T f(t,\omega) dt \right] < \infty$

and suppose $E[\int_S^T (f(t,\omega) - \phi_n(t,\omega))^2 dt]  \to 0$.

The Ito integral of $\phi_n$ is defined by

$$\int_S^T \phi_n (t,\omega) dB_t (\omega) = \sum_j e_{n,j}(\omega) \Delta B(t_j)$$

and the Ito integral of $f$ is defined by

$$\int_S^T f(t,\omega) dB_t (\omega) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_S^T \phi_n (t,\omega) dB_t (\omega)$$

where the limit is with respect to $L^2 (P)$.

---

My question is about the proof of Ito's isometry, that

$$E \left( \int_S^T f(t,\omega) dB_t (\omega) \right)^2 = E \int_S^T f(t,\omega)^2 dt$$

This clearly holds for elementary $\phi_n$ due to linearity of expectation and the fact that $\phi_n$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$-adapted. But why does the above definition mean it holds for general $f$ satisfying $1,2,3$. Specifically, writing:

$$E\left[\left(\int_S^T f(t,\omega) dB_t (\omega)\right)^2 \right]= E\left[ \lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\int_S^T \phi_n(t,\omega) dB_t (\omega)\right)^2 \right]$$

What is the justification for interchanging the expectation with the $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ in order to get the elementary Ito isometry to hold for the more general $f$?

Comment: If $X_n \to X$ in $L^2$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}(X_n^2) = \mathbb{E}(X^2)$. Use this for $$X := \int_S^T \phi_n(t) \, dB_t$$ and $$X:= \int_S^T f(t) \, dB_t.$$

Comment: Noted, thanks! I will make sure to remember that implication